# How to show huge data on ssrs report

Tags: performance, reporting-services, report, rendering

I have one ssrs report, output of sql stored procedure having 400k rows show withing in 30 seconds, but ssrs report takes too much time to render (around 5 to 6 minutes). report does not have any grouping, it is plain tablix report.
check report log in execution log 3 table, time taking for rendering report.

how to show such large no. of rows on ssrs report?

Comment: You have not included any code or data - to help others to help you, you should include as much background information and detail as you can. You are using the term "lacs" which I guess means 100,000? Have you tried storing the sp result in a temp table, then rendering from the temp table? Does the report need to join other tables, in which case indexing etc. may be relevant.

Comment: 400,000 rows seems a little too much for somebody to consume. If the tablix is simple then there is not much you can do about rendering times without reducing the columns or rows in the report or adding resource to the server. What does the end user actually do with the report? If they export it to Excel for instance then you could export it directly without having it render to screen first.

Comment: I agree with Alan. it's begs the question.. who is going to actually read a 400K line report? If the ultimate goal is to export the data to be consumed somewhere else, do it directly in the format that is required rather than use SSRS as an intermediate step.

Comment: thanks all for the reply. I want to say that, among 400000 rows, these 400000 rows includes category and subcategory, i want to page break for every category, means when report export to excel, every category will show in seperate sheet. and this category types are dynamic, means this can be increased, so due to this, i create group and on every tablix, sub category showing in column grouping. so, due to this grouping report becomes heavy and unable to render.